# Как найти дифф между 2 диффами?

Tags: git, diff, git-diff

Есть закоммиченный код. Есть набор изменений к нему в файле `patch_1.patch`. Я применяю эти изменения, но ещё не коммичу их. После этого делаю некоторые изменения и получаю `patch_2.patch`, который содержит в себе большинство изменений из `patch_1.patch` + некоторые конфликты с ним. Можно ли как-то получить дифф этих двух патчей так, чтобы можно было к закомиченному коду в итоге: 1) применить `patch_1.patch`; 2) применить дифф между патчами, получив в итоге результат, эквивалентный применению `patch_2.patch`? Другими словами, нужен дифф двух диффов.

Comment: Проще всего создать новую ветку. Закомитить сначал результат работы patch_1.patch, потом еще один комит после изменений. И потом сделать `git diff` чтоб получить новый патч.

Comment: @Roman-StopRUaggressioninUA "потом еще один комит после изменений." -> для этого нужен искомый патч

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Извлечь в отдельную папку оригинальную ревизию. 2) применить к ней patch_1.patch 3) сделать diff содержимого папок.

Comment: Можно 1 командой как-то, а не вручную?

Comment: диррективами препроцессора

Comment: @ARHovsepyan не понял

Comment: плохо да, когда не понятно? А вы сами почему оформляете вопрос не понятно _ ни по русски и ни по английски? Уважать нужно язык, на котором пишете, если даже это не ваш язык....